# how to read the last, which is also the highest number from sql table in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.Net application, which has a login page. I was working on the failed login attempt counter. The application uses SQL database and one of the fields in the table is called "LoginAttemptCount". This field is supposed to record every failed attempt as 1,2,3... and last one is 9. Now every time the failed attempt reaches 3, I want that specific user to be blocked for 5 minutes. 5 minutes later I would allow the user to be able to retry 3 more times and the application continues to work in the same pattern until it reaches 9. 
My problem is, what happens after the user failed to login 3 times and he is blocked for 5 minutes. If the application is still running, the next failed attempt says 4,5,6... However, if the user closes the application, opens it again and tries to login the attempt counter resets and records 1 instead of 4. So my question is how do I read the last attempt count, which had been saved in the database, which should be the highest number (3 according to my example), using the Username as a reference. I want to read the last recorded attempt count, which is 3 so that the 4th time the user fails to login, the database should record 4 but not 1 from scratch even if the application is closed and reopened.
The data for "LoginAttemptCount" field comes from the code I wrote and not from a textbox. Please do not ask me why I decided 3 to be the maximum attempt as that is not the point of this question.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
If Timer1.Enabled = True Then
                    MsgBox("Your account has been temporarily blocked! Please try again after " & lblcountdown.Text & " minutes.")

                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password! Please try again. Attempt " & Attempt & " of 9")
                    Attempt = Attempt + 1

                    Dim FailedUsername As String = txtUsername.Text
                    Dim LoginAttemptCount As String = Attempt + (-1)
                    Dim LoginLastDateTimeAttempt As String = Format(Date.Now, "MMMM dd, yyyy - h:mm:ss tt").ToString
                    Dim PasswordRetryAfter As String = TimeOfDay.AddMinutes(0.3) 'Date.Now.AddMinutes(5)   '5 = 5 minutes
                    Dim IP_Address As String = "IP_Address"

                    Fir_FailedLogin.First_FailedLoginAttempt(FailedUsername, LoginAttemptCount, LoginLastDateTimeAttempt, _
                                                PasswordRetryAfter, IP_Address)
                    'Sec_FailedLogin.Second_FailedLoginAttempt(FailedUsername, LoginAttemptCount, LoginLastDateTimeAttempt, _
                    '                            PasswordRetryAfter, IP_Address)
                    If Attempt = 4 Then
                        MsgBox("Hello " & FailedUsername & ", your Login attempt failed. " & Environment.NewLine _
                       & Environment.NewLine & " Your account is temporarily blocked. " & Environment.NewLine _
                       & Environment.NewLine & " Please try again after 5 minutes")
                        txtUsername.ReadOnly = True
                        txtPassword.ReadOnly = True
                        'Timer2.Start()
                        'lblClock.Text = TimeOfDay
                        Timer1.Enabled = True
                        lbltimer.Text = "30"    'Timer Max
                        lblcountdown.Text = "20"    'Count Down Max
                        lbltimer.Visible = False    'False turns off the visibility of the lbltimer.

                        Attempt = 4
                    ElseIf Attempt = 7 Then
                        MsgBox("Hello " & FailedUsername & ", your Login attempt failed. " & Environment.NewLine _
                       & Environment.NewLine & " Your account is temporarily blocked. " & Environment.NewLine _
                       & Environment.NewLine & " Please try again after 5 minutes")
                        txtUsername.ReadOnly = True
                        txtPassword.ReadOnly = True
                        'Timer2.Start()
                        'lblClock.Text = TimeOfDay
                        Timer1.Enabled = True
                        lbltimer.Text = "30"    'Timer Max
                        lblcountdown.Text = "20"    'Count Down Max
                        lbltimer.Visible = False    'False turns off the visibility of the lbltimer.

                        Attempt = 7
                    ElseIf Attempt = 10 Then
                        MsgBox("Hello " & FailedUsername & ", your Login attempt failed. " & Environment.NewLine _
                       & Environment.NewLine & " Your account is temporarily blocked. " & Environment.NewLine _
                       & Environment.NewLine & " Please try again after 5 minutes")
                        txtUsername.ReadOnly = True
                        txtPassword.ReadOnly = True
                        'Timer2.Start()
                        'lblClock.Text = TimeOfDay
                        Timer1.Enabled = True
                        lbltimer.Text = "30"    'Timer Max
                        lblcountdown.Text = "20"    'Count Down Max
                        lbltimer.Visible = False    'False turns off the visibility of the lbltimer.
                        'When the maximum attempt is reached reset the attempt to "Attempt = 1"
                        Attempt = 1
                    End If
                End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think you've got to rethink your log in process. 
The first thing I would recommend is to add to the users table a datetime column that will hold the date and time of the last failed log in attempt. Then, when the user tries to login, you need to add to the login where clause a condition to test if the LoginAttemptCount is either 0 or not a multiple of 3 (and if so, verify than the last login attempt was at least 5 minutes ago).
Also, you need to reset the LoginAttemptCount to 0 on every successful login.
All of this logic can be handled by the login stored procedure, so that the state of the program is irrelevant to the login attempts mechanism.

btw, what happens after the 9th failed login?

Comment: [Hi Zohar, Thank you for the reply and good feedback. I want to make few things clear. The code I posted is only a portion of the entire code. Just like you said my codes actually reset every failed attempt back to 0 provided that the user login successfully within the allowed 9 attempts. It's just I didn't post the code, which resets to 0. I picked 3 as a max attempt only for the purpose of testing the codes. At the end of the day, I would probably allow 5 attempts before blocking for 5 minutes.

Comment: [Also Instead of date and time to control the delay, I used timer. The last attempt will turn the timer ON. To be honest I think the Date and Time probably is a good idea. If you can help me how to use the Date and Time and communicate the code to the database it will be great. Your last question was what happens after 9. After 9 I want to force the user to change their password.]

Comment: Well, the major change in my approach vs. yours is that the entire login business logic should be the database responsibility. that will automatically disable the user's ability to reset your fail count by restarting the program.

What kind of database are you working with?

Comment: I use SQL Database. My database connection works fine when a user login. If the user failed to login few times, but manages to login within the first 9 attempts, my database connection deletes all previous records, for that specific user. My problem is how do I establish communication to the database and read how many times the user had failed from a specific field?

Comment: If I read/verify how many times the user failed before (for example 3 failed attempts in the database), then even if the application is closed and opened, I would be able to tell the database to record 4,5,6... the next time the user failed. One of my issue now is if the user closes and opens the application, it resets the counting back to 1,2,3 instead of 4,5,6.  Can you tell me some example on how the use date and time to keep track of the failed attempts? Best Regards.